# binarySearch Method Throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception - Java

Tags: java, exception, methods, binary-search, indexoutofboundsexception

I don't know why this method is throwing an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception.

`When I change the initial "high"` value to `"int high = array.length - 1;"`, the program will `return any integer value` that I search for.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

---

```
public class BinarySearch {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int searchValue = 12;
    int[] givenNums = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    binarySearch(givenNums, searchValue);
    System.out.println("\nResult: " + searchValue);

}

public static int binarySearch(int[] array, int key) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = array.length;
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    int i = 0;
    System.out.println();

    while (low <= high) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
        if (array[mid] < key) {
            low = mid + 1;
            mid = (low + high) / 2;
        } else if (array[mid] > key) {
            high = mid - 1;
            mid = (low + high) / 2;
        }
        else
            return mid;

        i++;
    }
    return -1;
}
}
```

Comment: You *just* posted [a very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827289/binarysearch-method-throwing-arrayindexoutofbounds-exception-java). You've already been told why this error happens: you cannot set high to `array.length`. Having the code fail to run to its completion is not preferable over having it fail to produce the correct answer (at least not in this case). You're not fixing anything by setting `high` to `array.length` instead of `array.length - 1`, you're only making things worse.

Comment: @user1735982.. See my post to understand what exactly you are doing..

Comment: Different method, different problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to be consistent about whether `high` means the maximum value it can be *inclusively* or *exclusively*. You start off with it being an exclusive upper bound:

```
int high = array.length;
```

But then your `while` loop condition is only appropriate if it's an *inclusive* upper bound:

```
while (low <= high)
```

You should probably just change the `while` condition to:

```
while (low < high)
```

... and change the assignment of `high` later, too.

Alternatively, you could keep it inclusive, and change the initial value to `array.length - 1`.

That will stop the situation where `low == high == mid == array.length`, which is where it would blow up.

I'd also suggest moving the `mid = (low + high) / 2` computation to be the first statement within the `while` loop - then you can get rid of the duplicate code.

```
while (low < high) {        
    mid = (low + high) / 2;
    System.out.print(i + " ");
    if (array[mid] < key) {
        low = mid + 1;
    } else if (array[mid] > key) {
        high = mid;
    }
    else {
        return mid;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The maximum index of an array is `array.length - 1` as they start from 0.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in java are indexed from 0, that means...

int[] arr = new int[10];

First value is arr[0] and last is arr[9], length is 10.